# Canceling alarm when activity is destroyed

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, alarm, repeatingalarm

I have a service running in my Android app. This service was started using an AlarmManager with a repeating alarm. When a certain event occurs, the service sends out a broadcast, which is received within a Fragment. There the alarm is canceled (alarm.cancel(pendingIntent)).

So far, so good. But what do I do if the activity/fragment gets destroyed? How can I still cancel the service?

Comment: Can't you just send out the broadcast and cancel the alarm right there in the service?

Comment: @V M I would like to cancel the alarm within the service, but how would I do that?

Comment: The same way you are cancelling in the fragment i guess?

Comment: I the fragment I have the instance of the AlarmManager, I don't have that in the service however.

Comment: Well in the service you have your application context, you can get your manager like this:  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); Where context is getApplicationContext().

Comment: @V M Thank you very much, it worked! Unfortunately nikis posted it as an answer, so I can't accept your comment as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call this `alarm.cancel()` with the same `pendingIntent` you've used to start it at the `onDestroy` method of Activity/Fragment:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pendingIntent)
```

From the description of `cancel()` method:

Remove any alarms with a matching `Intent`. Any alarm, of any type, whose `Intent` matches this one (as defined by `filterEquals(Intent)`), will be canceled.